# Прошу помощи с регулярным выражением, снова.

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Господа, помогите еще с регуляркой. Вот есть паттерн, который ищет то, что нужно: `\{\{(.*)\}\}` Надо сделать так, чтобы он искал все, кроме вхождений, начинающихся с {{Книга

`\{\{^Книга(.*)\}\}` - не работает, что я делаю не так?

Примерный текст такой:

> > Литература {{Книга||автор = Щербина П.С.|заглавие = Пчеловодство|год =
> > 1956}}
>
> 12 - Ссылки
>
> Ссылки {{Commons|Honey}}
>
> ```
> «Мёд» в энциклопедиях на Яндексе.
> ГОСТ 31766-2012. Меды монофлорные. Технические условия
> Чем полезен мёд и как его правильно выбрать
> ```
>
> {{Rq|style|sources}}
>
> Категория:Пчеловодство
> Категория:Русский народный быт {{Link
> FA|heк}}
>
> {{Link FA|hr}}
>
> {{Link FA|ja}}
>
> {{Link FA|scn}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот правильное регулярное выражение:

```
@\{\{((?!Книга).+)\}\}@iu
# (?!Книга) - негативный просмотр вперед (после символов {{ не встречается "Книга")
```

Answer (score -1):

> \{\{[^Книга].+\}\}

Comment: @Faydaen, у вас ошибка в выражении. Оно читается так:  
Если после символов {{ идет один из символов "к", "н", "и", "г" или "а" - прекратить выборку.